# How do I make ncat not send a line-feed?

Tags: powershell, netcat

I'm on Windows 7 Powershell and have ncat from http://nmap.org/ncat/

I'm trying to send "foo" to some network device

```
PS> ncat -u 192.168.1.255 6061
foo
```

but it sends "foo\n" (66 6f 6f 0a) and the line-feed makes the device not recognize the command.

there's a -C option to add a carriage return, but that's no help.

I made a text file containing "foo" and did

```
PS> cat .\test.txt | ncat -u 192.168.1.255 6061
```

but that also adds CRLF

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you just pipe "foo" | ncat ...

Failing that, you might want to look at this: http://powershell.codeplex.com/releases/view/59029

Which seems to allow you to send messages over TCP.

Answer (score 1):

in case someone comes along this question and is not working on Windows but rather on Linux, you might want to try this:

- Use the "eof" key, Ctrl+D

Source: [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/429128/how-can-i-force-netcat-to-send-my-input-immediately-not-just-on-newlines)